# Insert result set from UNPIVOT into table

Tags: sql, unpivot

I am trying to find the syntax for inserting the results from an UNPIVOT statement into an existing table in the database?

Comment: can you show us your UNPIVOT statement?

Comment: If you are using `Oracle` you could consider using `INSERT ALL` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50785949/5070879) instead of `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplest answer which works for any SELECT including UNPIVOT would be...

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT statement
```

However, this does require that your destination tables columns match your SELECT statement columns.

Although you can get around this limitation with...

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2....)
SELECT statement
```