# Oracle 11g: Unpivot multiple columns and include column name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

I'm triyng to unpivot multiple columns in my dataset. Here's what my data look like.

```
CREATE TABLE  T5 (idnum NUMBER,f1 NUMBER(10,5),f2 NUMBER(10,5),f3 NUMBER(10,5)
                 ,e1 NUMBER(10,5),e2 NUMBER(10,5)
                 ,h1 NUMBER(10,5),h2 NUMBER(10,5));

INSERT INTO T5 (IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2) 
VALUES (1,'10.2004','5.009','7.330','9.008','8.003','.99383','1.43243');
INSERT INTO T5 (IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2
VALUES (2,'4.2004','6.009','9.330','4.7008','4.60333','1.993','3.3243');
INSERT INTO T5 (IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2)
VALUES (3,'10.2040','52.6009','67.330','9.5008','8.003','.99383','1.43243');
INSERT INTO T5 (IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2)
VALUES (4,'9.20704','45.009','17.330','29.008','5.003','3.9583','1.243');

COMMIT;

select * from t5;

IDNUM    F1    F2     F3        E1      E2       H1     H2

1   10.2004 5.009   7.33    9.008   8.003   0.99383 1.43243
2   4.2004  6.009   9.33    4.7008  4.60333 1.993   3.3243
3   10.204  52.6009 67.33   9.5008  8.003   0.99383 1.43243
4   9.20704 45.009  17.33   29.008  5.003   3.9583  1.243
```

I'm unpivoting like so...

```
select *
from (select IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2,
      null as E3,null as H3
      from T5)
UnPivot((F,E,H) for sk in ((F1,E1,H1) as 1,
                              (F2,E2,H2) as 2,
                              (F3,E3,H3) as 3))
order by IDNUM,SK;

IDNUM  SK        F        E        H
-----  --  -------  -------  -------
    1   1  10.2004    9.008   .99383
    1   2    5.009    8.003  1.43243
    1   3     7.33     null     null
    2   1   4.2004   4.7008    1.993
    2   2    6.009  4.60333   3.3243
    2   3     9.33     null     null
    3   1   10.204   9.5008   .99383
    3   2  52.6009    8.003  1.43243
    3   3    67.33     null     null
    4   1  9.20704   29.008   3.9583
    4   2   45.009    5.003    1.243
    4   3    17.33     null     null
```

But what I really need is as follows...

```
IDNUM  SK        F        E        H  F_COL_NAME
-----  --  -------  -------  -------  ----------
    1   1  10.2004    9.008   .99383          F1
    1   2    5.009    8.003  1.43243          F2
    1   3     7.33     null     null          F3
    2   1   4.2004   4.7008    1.993          F1
    2   2    6.009  4.60333   3.3243          F2
    2   3     9.33     null     null          F3
    3   1   10.204   9.5008   .99383          F1
    3   2  52.6009    8.003  1.43243          F2
    3   3    67.33     null     null          F3
    4   1  9.20704   29.008   3.9583          F1
    4   2   45.009    5.003    1.243          F2
    4   3    17.33     null     null          F3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Something useful to assist potential answerers - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12446/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `select idnum, sk, f, e, h, 'F'||SK as col_name` ... You need to specify all columns instead of an asterix.

Like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12446/21

Answer (score 17):

Change your `UNPIVOT` to be like this

```
select *
from (
  select IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2,
    null as E3,null as H3
  from T5
) A
UnPivot(
  (F,E,H) for sk in (
    (F1,E1,H1) as 'F1',
    (F2,E2,H2) as 'F2',
    (F3,E3,H3) as 'F3')
)
order by IDNUM,SK
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I tried making my query in a similar fashion, but i get the error, "non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values"

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi just make it for example (F1,E1,H1) as 1, I'm not sure you can have letters etc in the as part so just use a number

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store result of `UNPIVOT` you could use `INSERT ALL`:

```
CREATE TABLE T5_unpiv(IDNUM NUMBER,SK NUMBER,F NUMBER,E NUMBER,H NUMBER
                     ,F_COL_NAME VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT ALL 
  INTO T5_unpiv(IDNUM,SK,F,E,H,F_COL_NAME) VALUES(idnum,1,f1,e1,h1,'F1')
  INTO T5_unpiv(IDNUM,SK,F,E,H,F_COL_NAME) VALUES(idnum,2,f2,e2,h2,'F2')
  INTO T5_unpiv(IDNUM,SK,F,E,H,F_COL_NAME) VALUES(idnum,3,f3,NULL,NULL,'F3')
SELECT * FROM T5;

SELECT * FROM T5_unpiv;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a571103c2f819435d267c70b5f6d339a)**

Output:

```
┌───────┬────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ IDNUM │ SK │    F    │    E    │    H    │ F_COL_NAME │
├───────┼────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────────┤
│     1 │  1 │ 10.2004 │ 9.008   │ .99383  │ F1         │
│     1 │  2 │   5.009 │ 8.003   │ 1.43243 │ F2         │
│     1 │  3 │    7.33 │ null    │ null    │ F3         │
│     2 │  1 │  4.2004 │ 4.7008  │ 1.993   │ F1         │
│     2 │  2 │   6.009 │ 4.60333 │ 3.3243  │ F2         │
│     2 │  3 │    9.33 │ null    │ null    │ F3         │
│     3 │  1 │  10.204 │ 9.5008  │ .99383  │ F1         │
│     3 │  2 │ 52.6009 │ 8.003   │ 1.43243 │ F2         │
│     3 │  3 │   67.33 │ null    │ null    │ F3         │
│     4 │  1 │ 9.20704 │ 29.008  │ 3.9583  │ F1         │
│     4 │  2 │  45.009 │ 5.003   │ 1.243   │ F2         │
│     4 │  3 │   17.33 │ null    │ null    │ F3         │
└───────┴────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
select * from (select IDNUM,F1,F2,F3,E1,E2,H1,H2, null as E3,null as H3 from  T5) UnPivot((F,E,H) for sk in ((F1,E1,H1) as 'F1',
                          (F2,E2,H2) as 'F2',
                          (F3,E3,H3) as 'F3')) order by IDNUM,SK;
```