# Is there any way to order the result set by what you want in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

Is there any way to select from SQL Server by 'Queue, serie ...'.

For example I want to get some rows by using identifier.

I want to get rows ordered by like C, D, A, F

```
SELECT * 
FROM BRANCH 
WHERE IDENTIFIER IN ('C', 'D', 'A', 'F')
```

And this query turns rows order by random.

Maybe ordered as

- **'F', 'D', 'A', 'C'**
- **'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'**

How can I get the result set ordered as 'C', 'D', 'A', 'F'? I need this using for `for xml path` usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM dbo.BRANCH b
JOIN (
    VALUES
        (1, 'C'),
        (2, 'D'),
        (3, 'A'),
        (4, 'F')
) c(ID, IDENTIFIER) ON c.IDENTIFIER = b.IDENTIFIER
ORDER BY c.ID
```

Comment: Is that possible for Oracle ? I mean not ordering. is there any using in pl sql like 'values' syntax

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747355/oracle-11g-unpivot-multiple-columns-and-include-column-name