# Oracle SQL - Unpivot kind of logic but without hard coding

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, unpivot

I have table like below , there are many number of lines with debit/Credit string and respective amounts in a table , need to bring as expected table like in separate lines of each strings and its respective amounts , how can i achieve this, appreciate your help!

| Debit String | Credit String | Debit Amount | Credit Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ING1 | ING2 | 123 | 0 |
| INT2 | INT5 | 234 | 0 |

Expected Result is :-

| String | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| ING1 | 123 |
| INT2 | 234 |
| ING2 | 0 |
| INT5 | 0 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle 11g: Unpivot multiple columns and include column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747355/oracle-11g-unpivot-multiple-columns-and-include-column-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  (string, amount) FOR type IN (
    (debit_string,  debit_amount ) AS 'D',
    (credit_string, credit_amount) AS 'C'
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Debit_String, Credit_String, Debit_Amount, Credit_Amount) AS
SELECT 'ING1', 'ING2', 123, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'INT2', 'INT5', 234, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TYPE | STRING | AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | D | ING1 | 123 |
> | C | ING2 | 0 |
> | D | INT2 | 234 |
> | C | INT5 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6ff38b7d63717334802df42b2ad0d0fd)*